# Problem using generic views in django

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-csrf

I'm currently working with django generic views and I have a problem I can't figure out.

When using delete_object I get a TypeError exception:

```
delete_object() takes at least 3 non-keyword arguments (2 given)
```

Here is the code (I have ommited docstrings and imports):

views.py

```
def delete_issue(request, issue_id):
    return delete_object(request,
                         model = Issue,
                         object_id = issue_id,
                         template_name = 'issues/delete.html',
                         template_object_name = 'issue')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('issues.views',
    (r'(?P<issue_id>\d+)/delete/$', 'delete_issue'),
)
```

The other generic views (object_list, create_object, etc.) work fine with those parameters. Another problem I have is when using the create_object() function, it says something about a CSRF mechanism, what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `post_delete_redirect`, this means url, where user should be redirected after object is deleted. You can find this in view signature:

```
def delete_object(request, model, post_delete_redirect, object_id=None,
        slug=None, slug_field='slug', template_name=None,
        template_loader=loader, extra_context=None, login_required=False,
        context_processors=None, template_object_name='object'):
```

Comment: I thought it wasn't required. Thanks.